# Google cache does not have prerendered _escaped_fragment version of page, rather it is showing another page altogether

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot

I have read multiple questions around it but still could not find a solution. We have a page in the form `https://example.com/trending`. We are using Prerender using the `?_escaped_fragment` url to show cached version of the pages to Googlebot. We have double checked Prerender cache and the page looks properly cached over there.

Now the issue is when we see google cache for `https://example.com/trending` it shows the search page of the site `https://example.com/search` and it does not even show the prerendered html version of the page. Strangely this is only happening to a sample of pages so this is not an issue with site overall.

Comment: Google's AJAX crawling with `_escaped_fragment` has been [deprecated for two years](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more).   My guess is that Google is starting to no longer support it.

Comment: We have also had at least two other questions recently about Google showing the wrong page in cache.   Here is one I could find: [Google showing wrong cached page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108209/google-showing-wrong-cached-page)   Google may be getting its wires crossed somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I think former seems to be a more valid option. Seems a bit strange that this happens for a sample of the pages. Also all these pages show the same `https://example.com/search` page. The HTML is the same as when doing a "Fetch as Google" on the non prerendered URL. So Google is definitely not crawling the JS correctly and not even picking the prerendered version.

Comment: I'm not sure that "Fetch as Google" works with (or has ever worked with) `_escaped_fragment`.   I know it doesn't work with any URLs that have hashes (`#`) in them that the JavaScript uses to AJAX the content.    I'm not sure I can be more helpful in tracking down this problem.   I don't have any further experience in this area.